# Change what a pointer points to after you return it in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm working on a C++ project and I need a little sanity check and help on it.  I want to return a void* pointer to a memory location in an array (which I'll do by

```
void* pointer = (void*) (array+index);
```

).  The array is of chars so the indexing/byte numbering works out pretty nicely.

However, I want to be able to change what memory this location points to later on (a different spot in the array) as a response to some conditions in the code.  Is there a way to do this?  I'm messing around with void** pointers and trying to return a reference to the spot in memory where I stored the pointer, so I can just change the memory where the pointer itself is stored and change what pointer is read.  I'm having trouble on the syntax to do this, though, and I'm not entirely sure it's possible.

I'm working within fairly rigid constraints and I can't get around the fact that I have to return the void* pointer, otherwise I think there are probably some nicer ways around this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How can you talk about "sanity checks" when you're dealing with `void*`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if you want to point to something else, just assign the pointer to another value.

Comment: How can you talk about "sanity checks" when you're using C-style casts?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply reassign the pointer:

```
char array[1200];

void * p = array + 17;

// later:

p = array + 29;
```

(No need for the cast, since object pointers are implicitly convertible to void pointers.)

Answer (score 0):

to point somewhere else just cast the pointer back to char*, do your pointer arithmetics and that's it.

```
char *ptr_tmp = (char*)pointer;

ptr_tmp += 100;

pointer = (void*)ptr_tmp;
```

this is what I understood your problem is?!